# Synchronize WPF MediaElement Video with second window

Tags: wpf, mediaelement

I'm playing a video with the WPF MediaElement and OnButton Click it opens a second window (I move it with Screens.AllScreens[1] to my second monitor). 
On second window I've created a new instance of mediaelement and put the value from mediaelement1.position to mediaelemnt2.position.
Now I have a one second delay in my second window :(.

Is there a way to handle this?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a VisualBrush. 
Just send mediaElement to 2nd windows and apply VisualBrush.
Sample : rect.Fill = new VisualBrush(mediaElement);